# I write a python code for keep data and save it into sqlite db and this is my error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Personal_id'

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def log_in(patient):
    with conn:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO patient_office_syndrome VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (patient.Personal_id,patient.first_name, patient.last_name, patient.age, patient.phone, patient.gender, patient.weight, patient.height))


patient_1 = ('1409903748846541','siri','pat','25','06119433332',0,'80','190')

log_in(patient_1)


conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "c:\Users\User\Desktop\db_and_admin_web\main.py", line 19, in
> <module> log_in(patient_1) File
> "c:\Users\User\Desktop\db_and_admin_web\main.py", line 11, in
> log_in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
> (patient.Personal_id,patient.first_name, patient.last_name,
> patient.age, patient.phone, patient.gender, patient.weight,
> patient.height)) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute
> 'Personal_id'

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `patient`?
The syntax in your question implies that you want to use a `namedtuple`.

For example, define `patient` to be the following:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Patient = namedtuple('Patient', ('personal_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', ...))
patient = Patient(42, 'John', 'Doe', ...)
```

then use it this way:

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO patient_office_syndrome VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (patient.personal_id,patient.first_name, patient.last_name, ...)
```

Alternatively (and perhaps simpler), you can implement `patient` as a dict.